# Are the only changes in ADO.Net for .Net 4 in Entity Framework?

Tags: ado.net, .net-4.0

It seems from the [MSDN overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6y04yf.aspx) that the only change to ADO.Net in .Net 4 is the addition of Entity Framework.

I'm working on refactoring some legacy database access to use ADO.Net and one of the things I'd like to document as project issues is any benefit from moving to .Net 4 from the .Net 3.5sp1 we're currently targeting (we have a WPF GUI - it's a pure desktop app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a lot of improvement on linq-to-SQL as well see here, and that was for beta2, don't know if more stuff made it in the Release:

http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40